# Change button's state from another element's behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

The code I'm writing is on **ASP.net** Web Forms and I'm very new on this field of expertise, but I simplified it to run in pure HTML so that you might be able to help me through scoping into my code from jsfiddle.net. I require to perform few tasks in this snippet of code where some short code(so I believe) is stopping me do accomplish that. I'm writing below of what I ask help from devs to do:

- The Save button should be disabled by default and re-enable itself
  whenever one of the inputs has been changed (filled with some info).
- After it has been re-enabled in order to be clicked, I have put a
  jQuery code that triggers/toggles a class to perform a smooth
  progress filling button. I need that CSS transition to run once and
  after it's finished to reset the visual of the button to the default 
  as it looks on the first sight.

Here's the 
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AlbanNurkollari/fs4L3hqc/2/)**.

```
<head>
    <style>
         #formProfile {
             z-index: 1;
             float: left;
             left: 10px;
             top: 15px;
             position: relative;
             height: 620px;
             width: 500px;
         }
         #userProfileTab {
             position: absolute;
             border-top-left-radius: 10px;
             border-top-right-radius: 10px;
             background-color: teal;
             color: whitesmoke;
             font-size: 36px;
             font-weight: 900;
             font-family: Calibri;
             text-align: center;
             line-height: 170%;
             height: 10%;
             width: 40%;
             top: 0;
             left: 30%;
         }
         #userProfileContainer {
             position: absolute;
             border: 3px solid teal;
             border-radius: 10px;
             height: 89%;
             width: 90%;
             top: 10%;
             left: 5%;
             overflow: auto;
         }
         #profileLabels {
             position: absolute;
             top: 3%;
             left: 0;
             /*border: 2px outset teal;
                    border-radius: 10px;*/
             height: 490px;
             width: 44%;
         }
         #profileFields {
             position: absolute;
             /*border: 2px outset teal;
                    border-radius: 10px;*/
             height: 490px;
             width: 55%;
             top: 3%;
             left: 44%;
         }
         .labels {
             position: absolute;
             border: none;
             border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
             height: 38px;
             width: 90%;
             line-height: 150%;
             color: #848484;
             font-family: Calibri;
             font-size: 24px;
             text-align: right;
             left: 5%;
         }
         .labels:after {
             content:'';
             position: relative;
             left: 3%;
             border-right: 1px solid silver;
         }
         .textBox {
             position: absolute;
             border: 1px dotted black;
             display: block;
             background-color: white;
             box-sizing: border-box;
             color: black;
             height: 34px;
             width: 95%;
             left: 2%;
             margin-top: 2px;
             margin-bottom: 2px;
             text-align: center;
             font-family: Calibri;
             font-style: italic;
             font-size: 16px;
             text-decoration: none;
             outline: 0;
             opacity: 0.75;
             -moz-transition: all .3s;
             -o-transition: all .3s;
             -webkit-transition: all .3s;
             transition: all .3s;
         }
         .textBox:hover {
             opacity: 1;
             border: none;
             background: whitesmoke;
             -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
             -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
             box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
             -moz-transition: none;
             -o-transition: none;
             -webkit-transition: none;
             transition: none;
         }
         .textBox:focus {
             border-radius: 10px;
             border-style: solid;
             border-width: 2px;
             background-color: lightskyblue;
             color: white;
             font-size: 20px;
             opacity: 1;
             -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) !important;
             -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) !important;
             box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) !important;
         }
        .btnSave {
            position: absolute;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: white;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 2px solid teal;
            border-radius: 10px;
            outline: none;
            top: 558px;
            left: 330px;
        }
        .buttonFull {
            border: 2px solid teal;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: white;
            position: absolute;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 0 silver;
            cursor: pointer;
            overflow:hidden;
            transition: all .1s linear;
        }
        .buttonFull:active {
            box-shadow: none;
            transform: translateY(2px);
        }
        #saveButtonFull {
            top: 480px;
            left: 330px;
        }
        #resetButtonFull {
            top: 480px;
            left: 200px;
        }
        .save, .reset {
            position:absolute;
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 900;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 10;
            -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
        }
        .save {
            top:7px;
            left:30px;
        }
        .reset {
            top:7px;
            left:27px;
        }
        #savedTick, #resetTick {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 7px;
            left: 50px;
            color: white;
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 20;
            text-shadow: #99FF66 0px 0px 10px;
        }
        .inner {
            background:#1d9650;
            /*border-radius: 7px;*/
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            text-align: center;
            width:0;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900) !important;
            -moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900) !important;
            -o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900) !important;
            transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900) !important;
            /* custom */
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900);
            -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900);
            -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900);
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.040, 0.240, 0.900);
            /* custom */
        }
        .progressBar {
            width: 100px !important;
        }
        .textColorize {
            left: 26px;
            color: white;
        }
        .notransition {
            -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
            /* Safari */
            transition-delay: 1s;
            width: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //var $heightBody = $(window).height() / 2;
            //var $heightParent = document.getElementById("formLogIn").clientHeight / 2;
            var $widthBody = $(window).width() / 2;
            var $widthParent = document.getElementById("formProfile").clientWidth / 2;
            //var $mrgTop = $heightBody - $heightParent;
            var $mrgLeft = $widthBody - $widthParent;

            $("body").css("margin-left", $mrgLeft);

            $("#saveButtonFull").on("click", function () {
                //$(this).off("click");
                $(".inner").toggleClass("progressBar");
                $(".save").html("Saved").toggleClass('textColorize');
                //$(".inner").addClass("notransition").removeClass("notransition");
                //$(".save").toggleClass('textColorize');

        });

   </script>

</head>

<body>
    <form id="formProfile">
        <div id="userProfileTab">Profile</div>
        <div id="userProfileContainer">
            <div id="profileLabels"> <span id="lblFirstName" class="labels" style="border-top: 1px solid silver;">* First Name</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblSurname" class="labels">* Surname</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblBirdthay" class="labels">* Birthday</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblGender" class="labels">* Gender</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblEmail" class="labels">* E-mail</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblPhone" class="labels">Phone</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblCountry" class="labels">Country/State</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblCity" class="labels">City/Town</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblAddress1" class="labels">Address 1</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblAddress2" class="labels">Address 2</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblZip" class="labels">Zip/Postal Code</span>

                <br/>
                <br/> <span id="lblSignature" class="labels">Signature</span>

            </div>
            <div id="profileFields">
                <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" class="textBox"</input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtSurname" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtBirthday" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtGender" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtEmail" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtPhone" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtCountry" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtCity" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtAddress1" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtAddress2" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtZip" class="textBox"></input>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" id="txtSignature" class="textBox"></input>
            </div>

            <div id="resetButtonFull" class="buttonFull"> 
                <span id="resetTick">&#10004;</span>
                <span class="reset">Reset</span>
            </div>

            <div id="saveButtonFull" class="buttonFull"> 
                <span id="savedTick">&#10004;</span>
                <span class="save">Save</span>
                <div class="inner"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: You can do something like this:

```
var flag = false;
$('.textBox').on('keyup',function(e){
       if(this.value)
       {
           flag = true;
           console.log(flag);
       }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            console.log(flag);
        }
    });
```

On the basis of this flag you can enable/disable your save button. Since you are using a div for the 'SAVE' Button. You can grey it out to show it as disabled. And in your button 'onClick' event-handler you can put an 'if' condition for this 'flag'. Let me know if this helps and I can help you further.